# Script to set windows (vista) DNS settings

Tags: windows, dns

I'd like to create a script that will toggle between setting the DNS settings of my wireless card between automatic selection and a particular IP (openDNS).

Can this be done, and if so what should I look in to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would look at Powershell to do this.  I found a post on how to change your ip settings in a one liner.

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where-object -filterscript { $_.IPEnabled -eq ‘True’ -and $_.ServiceName -eq ‘E100B’ } | foreach-object -process { $_.EnableStatic(’192.168.1.200′,’255.255.0.0′) }
```

[Author of this code's original post](http://www.leedesmond.com/weblog/?p=84)

Answer (score 0):

I would use netsh (google for it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link back.
Here is some info that may be helpful:

- [Still Very Much Alive and Kicking - netsh](http://www.leedesmond.com/weblog/?p=154)
- Tutorial PowerShell v3: TCP/IPv4 (and IPv6) Network Basics - [Part I](http://www.leedesmond.com/weblog/?p=807) and [Part II](http://www.leedesmond.com/weblog/?p=811)

Comment: SO doesn't really appreciate posting of links alone.